# HTML5 <audio> play before 'canplaythrough' event in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari, dom-events

I am trying to add an `<audio>` tag to my page, and am worried about audio loading. Specifically about the longer audios taking a (relatively) long time to load with slow internet.

After looking into the `<audio>` loading events I found `canplay` and `canplaythrough`. Once the `canplaythrough` event has fired I can play the audio no problem, but for some reason I am unable to get it to play between the `canplay` and `canplaythrough` events, even though it should work.

How can I get the audio to start playing after `canplay` but before `canplaythrough`?

I am also open to non-native solutions (3rd party JS libraries) to enable this sort of chunked playback (playing before it's fully loaded).

---

EDIT: Turns out this only happens in Safari, though I am still looking for potential solutions.

(Tested in Safari `12.1.2 (14607.3.9)`, Firefox `69.0`, and Chrome `76.0.3809.132`, all running on macOS `10.14.6 (18G87)`)

---

Example:

```html
<audio id="audioElement" src="audio.mp3" preload="none" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    console.log('document.DOMContentLoaded');

    const audioElement = document.getElementById('audioElement');

    audioElement.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
      console.log('audioElement.canplay');
      audioElement.play();
    });
    audioElement.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => {
      console.log('audioElement.canplaythrough');
    });

    audioElement.addEventListener('play', () => {
      console.log('audioElement.play');
    });
    audioElement.addEventListener('playing', () => {
      console.log('audioElement.playing');
    });
    audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', (e) => {
      console.log('audioElement.timeupdate', audioElement.currentTime);
    });

    console.log('Loading...')
    audioElement.load();
  });
</script>
```

Output:

```
> audioElement.canplay
> audioElement.play
> audioElement.playing
> audioElement.timeupdate – 0

[ pause of about 5-10 seconds ]

> audioElement.canplaythrough

[ audio actually starts playing ]

> audioElement.timeupdate – 0.135390108
> audioElement.timeupdate – 0.385407534
> audioElement.timeupdate – 0.636663779
> audioElement.timeupdate – 0.887541244
> audioElement.timeupdate – 1.137894301
> audioElement.timeupdate – 1.388934644
> audioElement.timeupdate – 1.64044203
> audioElement.timeupdate – 1.894268825
> audioElement.timeupdate – 2.139506962
```

Comment: Any luck getting past this? I have the same problem, canplay event fires but audio doesn't actually play until canplaythrough event fires.